# Manage a player character suffering amnesia?

Tags: gm-techniques, wfrp-2e

I'm going to manage a group with one character suffering of deep amnesia, Warhammer 2nd edition.

How do I manage the character's skills, talents and profile?

I think the profile is the same and talents are the same as before the amnesia, depending on physics and/or magic, but competence is reset.

Comment: Whatever you do, read up on real life amnesia and do not make a cheap stereotype of it in your game. Because doing so does a disservice to your player and reality is often stranger than fiction. Depending on what sort of amnesia the character has, their skills/talents/profiles will be differently affected.

Comment: Plot twist: Have the player believe to have and so "re-develop" a certain skill-set, then, reaching a milestone in the campaign, have it revealed that most of the info about who the character is is wrong, because it was about their twin (about whom they should not really hear previous to this, but you may very subtly imply their existence, so that it doesn't entirely come out of the blue.)

Comment: i think it might depends on skills, if you search for examples from real life, you might examples of people which they skills were not affected by amnesia (ie some musicians)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amnesia is a great story-telling trait that is not specifically addressed in the WFRP 2e RAW (the word does not appear in the Core Rulebook or *Tome of Corruption*--where I might expect it to appear as result of a mutation).

As GM, you should not restrict the player's Starting, Advance or Current Profile. However, Skills represent that player's ability to perform something that the Amnesia would effectively block.

As the player, real world Amnesia can take on many forms and "depths"--for instance most do not forget vocabulary or language skills, but forget personal things. Wikipedia is one source for the player to use in building character depth (though should not be considered clinical research).

These two things should be worked out by the player and the GM before the campaign is too far along, first or second session.

Mechanically, here are some things I might do as a GM—assuming a general amnesia that wipes personal experience and mid-term memories like work skills, name, familiar relationships, etc.:

1. Force all **Basic** skill rolls as **unskilled** (1/2
   characteristic) for a predetermined number of tries, e.g., 5
   attempts, each attempt incrementally improving the roll by some %
   to full ability.
2. For *Advanced* Skills that require learning, I would force the
   player to devise story elements to remember them. Further, I might
   restrict access to them entirely without succeeding a Hard (-20%) or
   Very Hard (-30%) WP or Int test (or maybe spending a Fate point if
   the amnesia is *really deep*!) **and** providing a story element to
   use, e.g., Swim... the player is pushed into the sewer by the Skaven
   slave: does he drown? spend a Fate point? succeed a test? remember
   teaching a small child (son/daughter?) how to fetch a turtle? Force
   a story from the player and adjust the difficulty accordingly, maybe
   requiring a number of attempts before fully accessing the Advanced
   skill later.
3. Talents? Night Vision is something he/she has naturally. Each talent
   may require some work in the character background.

Now, advancement, learning new skills, etc. Play that as RAW, *unless* there is a prerequisite that is expected. The character is not beyond learning new things, so normal XP advancement should be allowed. Maybe remove the XP cost (200XP) for jumping careers (one time only). After all, the PC doesn't really know why he/she is good at one thing and could just as well do this "other" thing.

Amnesia is going to be a big flavor and story element in the PC and game. Don't let the PC forget it either (pun intended!). At some point the amnesia may be magically healed or overcome, decide up front with the player what that expectation is and when it might happen in the character's arc.

Comment: +1 overall.  Wikipedia should be treated in the same way as "Dude down the pub told me..." However, it is not a bad starting point.

Comment: "The dude down at the pub..." *LOVE IT* Wikipedia is really good for "close enough," not clinical research; so very much agree.